# Building packages using sbt-git results in "SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT" version qualifier

Tags: git, sbt, version

We're using SBT with [sbt-git](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git) to derive the version of our build from the Git revision. Specifically, we're using the output from `git describe` as version number and append the "SNAPSHOT" qualifier when the current revision is not tagged:

```
val versionRegex = "v([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)-?(.*)?".r

git.useGitDescribe := true
git.baseVersion := "0.0.0"
git.gitTagToVersionNumber := {
  case versionRegex(v, "") => Some(v)
  case versionRegex(v, "SNAPSHOT") => Some(s"$v-SNAPSHOT")
  case versionRegex(v, s) => Some(s"$v-$s-SNAPSHOT")
  case _ => None
}
```

However, this sometimes results the qualifier being duplicated, i.e. version numbers like "0.0.0-12345678-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT".

I can find no apparent reason for that. Removing "-SNAPSHOT" from the `gitTagToVersionNumber` solves the issue, but removes the qualifier completely in other cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sbt-git will append an additional qualifier when there are uncommited changes in the Git working copy during the build.

By default, this qualifier is set to "SNAPSHOT". One can change it through the `uncommittedSignifier` setting, e.g.:

```
git.uncommittedSignifier := Some("DIRTY")
```